# I would like to know how G/W handles multiple requests. [Java]

Tags: java, spring

I uploaded it because there was a problem that was not solved during development.
First of all, the language is Java

If you're curious about something

It's a structure where Http communication comes in from the client, answers from the G/W server, and requests Http to the other server
Delays occur for more than 3 seconds while receiving a response from the Other Server.
The client source cannot be modified and the G/W server continues to wait for a response from the other server before responding to the client
I think Thread waste is too much. Is there a way to minimize Thread waste?

The Other Server request is considered unreasonable until the Client HTTP request is received and answered.

```
            Runnable apiCallTask = () -> {
                try {
                    finalOs.write(postDataBytes);
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader2 = new InputStreamReader(finalConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
                    Reader inw = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader2);
                    for (int c; (c = inw.read()) >= 0; ){
                        sb.append((char) c);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            };

            // apiCallTask.run();
            executorService.submit(apiCallTask);
            executorService.shutdown();
```

Comment: What is "G/W"?  Please don't use contextually unclear or idiosyncratic abbreviations that other people will have difficulty understanding.  Or if you do, *introduce them*; e.g. "in the field of software engineering (SE) ...".

Comment: Is G/W a gateway server?  If so, it, and any proxy for that matter, will create a thread per request.  This is by no means wasteful, the threads only live as long as the request does so if the concern is too many threads waiting, then optimize the server side.  In any case, as the previous comment applies, you should define what a G/W server is.

Comment: The G/W server is the gateway server.
What I'm concerned about is assuming that requests from the client are continuing to come in
The G/W server will take longer to respond because the response from the other server is delayed by 3 seconds
Since we generate as many threads as we request, if we receive more than 1000 requests, I think the server will be loaded that much